# No content in LineChart (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

This is the code I'm using to try to generate a line in my LineChart (with the use of JavaFX).

```
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> graphChart;

public void fillGraphChart() {  

    graphChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
    //creating the chart
    graphChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);


    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("My portfolio");
    //populating the series with data
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

    graphChart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    graphChart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    graphChart.getData().add(series);
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

The problem is, no line appears. The only thing that changes is the title and
the axis'.
I tried a lot of different things but can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The error it throws now:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.calculateRequiredSize(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.autoRange(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.computePrefHeight(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$28(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$117/1472726303.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$363(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$41/809277467.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit2: my FMXL:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="eventListeners.MainWindow">
       <children>
          <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="25.0" layoutX="170.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="1030.0" />
          <TreeView fx:id="menuTree" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
          <Text fx:id="tabTitle" layoutX="599.0" layoutY="17.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Hashtag Statistics">
             <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
             </font></Text>
          <ImageView fx:id="logoutImage" fitHeight="14.0" fitWidth="14.0" layoutX="1183.0" layoutY="5.0" onMouseClicked="#logOut" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
          <ImageView fx:id="refreshImage" fitHeight="14.0" fitWidth="14.0" layoutX="1161.0" layoutY="5.0" onMouseClicked="#refresh" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
          <Line endX="5.0" endY="-20.0" layoutX="1173.0" layoutY="20.0" startX="5.0" startY="5.0" />
          <Line endX="373.0" endY="-30.0" layoutX="783.0" layoutY="29.0" startX="373.0" startY="-5.0" />
          <TextArea fx:id="recentTweets" editable="false" layoutY="641.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="1200.0" visible="false" />
          <TableView fx:id="dbTable" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="616.0" prefWidth="880.0" visible="false">
             <contextMenu>
                <ContextMenu fx:id="tableMenu">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#set50Rows" text="View 50 rows" />
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#set100Rows" text="View 100 rows" />
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setAllRows" text="View all rows" />
                  </items>
                </ContextMenu>
             </contextMenu>
          </TableView>
          <TreeView fx:id="tableTree" layoutX="1050.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="616.0" prefWidth="150.0" visible="false" />
          <PieChart fx:id="languagePie" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="616.0" prefWidth="1030.0" visible="false" />
          <LineChart fx:id="graphChart" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="616.0" prefWidth="1030.0" visible="false">
            <xAxis>
              <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
              <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
            </yAxis>
          </LineChart>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: With `FXML` you can leave `graphChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);` out of it. I think. Because that part gets handled in the `.fxml` file.

Comment: Yes @WonderWorld is right, remove that graphChart instantiation line. Otherwise you are creating new instance that is **not in scene graph**. The `@FXML` annotation will ensure instantiation of it by FXMLLoader.

Comment: I removed the line, it now throws out an error: "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String". No info on what line the error is.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: @lars can you post what there is in the `start` method too pls? Because if you are doing https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm this example with `fxml` then certain things would needed to be handled differently.

Comment: @WonderWorld There isn't a start method. This function is placed in the controller class of the FXML file. There is a initialize() method but there's nothing related to the LineChart in there.

Comment: You probably need to show the relevant FXML too.

Comment: @lars There has to be a class file with `@Override public void start(Stage stage){ // some code}` method. Your program won't run without it.

Comment: @WonderWorld The `start()` method presumably just loads the FXML file and shows the stage; it should be pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @James_D if thats the case then you're right. Was wondering because the error log shows `javafx.scene.` thought it might have something to do with whats in the `start()` method.

Comment: @Lars, is there other charts in the code?

Comment: @UlukBiy there's a PieChart, but I think that's irrelevant too, it's working fine without any errors, the error is thrown by the fillGraphChart() function.

Comment: Well it looks like you have set a `CategoryAxis` as one of the axes, which won't work with the data you are setting. But you really need to show the FXML...

Comment: Oops, correcting. @Lars change `CategoryAxis` to `NumberAxis` in fxml file for graphChart.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. You were right @Uluk Biy, changing this made it work!